# How to restrict EMR notebooks to specific users or IPs?

Tags: amazon-emr

When creating an EMR notebook and attach it to a cluster, it is available to the wide open world to everyone. This is surely not ideal. How can one restrict it to certain users/passwords or certain IP addresses?

Answer (score 1):

In EMR notebooks, "${aws:userId}" tag is added to each notebook. You can use this tag to restrict notebook operations(open, describe, etc) for that specific user who created that notebook.

Sample IAM user policy which restricts EMR notebook operations at user level,

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "elasticmapreduce:DescribeEditor",
                "elasticmapreduce:StartEditor",
                "elasticmapreduce:StopEditor",
                "elasticmapreduce:DeleteEditor",
                "elasticmapreduce:OpenEditorInConsole"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "elasticmapreduce:ResourceTag/creatorUserId": "${aws:userId}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

More info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-fine-grained-cluster-access.html#emr-managed-notebooks-tags-examples